# Node Js - Mongo dynamic query from string array

Tags: asp.net, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a string array like `['flat','flat shoes','shoes','black shoes']`.

And mongo collection has a field called called '`KeyWords`' which is a string.

I need to write a query to get the elements with '`KeyWords`' containing any of the items from the string array.

Example collection

```
{
 "KeyWords" : [
         "MEN'S SMART SHOES- FIREBACK LEATHER SLIP ON SHOES TAN",
         "G670",
         "SMART SHOES",
         "FIREBACK SHOES",
         "SHOES"
 ]}
{
 "KeyWords" : [
         "MEN'S SMART SHOES- FIREBACK LEATHER SLIP ON SHOES TAN",
         "G670",
         "SMART SHOES",
         "FIREBACK SHOES",
         "SHOES"
 ]
}
```

Can anybody suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: you tagged the question with asp.net, php , node.js .. r u sure you tagged correctly ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma, this requirement is part of my ASP.Net application where we are using Node JS. Tagged with PHP, because most of the PHP developers are using Mongo. Thought I can get suggestions from them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$in` for exact matches:

```
var keywords = ['flat','flat shoes','shoes','black shoes'];
YourModel.find({ KeyWords: { $in : keywords } }, ...);
```

For substring matches, you could use a regular expression query:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + keywords.join("|") + ")\\b", "i"); // "i" means case insensitive
YourModel.find({ KeyWords : regexp }, ...);
```

`\b` matches a word-boundary, so the regular expression will match *'very good flat shoes'* but not *'very good flatshoes'*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I am not wrong "$in" clause looks for exact matches. I need to get the elements having KeyWords like " very good flat shoes". Looking for KeyWords containing any of the item from array.

Comment: Thanks robert. Will try this and let you know.

Comment: Robert, I have edited my question with example collection. Modified my collection to have Keywords array. I am trying $in clause query "KeyWords": [{ "$in": searchParams }]. Where searchParams is an array. But it is not retuning any results. In console it is the query is looking like '{ KeyWords: [ { '$in': [Object] } ] }' where Object is the array of string.

Comment: You're passing an array as value for the query, but that needs to be an object (so not `[{ "$in": searchParams }]` but `{ "$in": searchParams }`). Also, `$in` is case-sensitive: `shoes` doesn't match `SHOES`. I edited my answer to make the regular expression search case-insensitive.